# How can I identify the types of ads by pulling data from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

act_xxxx/campaigns?fields=id,name,status,adsets{id,name,status,ads{id,name,status,creative{object_story_spec}}}

**I've been exploring how to identify whether the ad posted to Facebook is either image, video, carousal, single image, multiple image, etc...**

what way did you guys find out to identify those types?